# putting variables in text file then get them back in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, filewriter, printwriter

I have done most of my project but I still have one. I have to take data from the user and put it into 3 variables (`profit2012`, `profit2013`, `profit2014`), then store them in a text file separated by commas.  After that I want to take them back out of the file to draw them on a graph (Canvas). How can I do that?

```
private static int year() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selectedYear;
    System.out.println("Choose one of the following years: ");
    System.out.println("[1] 2012 - - [2] 2013 - - [3] 2014");
    selectedYear = input.nextInt();

    if (selectedYear == 1) {
        int Expenses2012;
        System.out.println("Please enter Expenses for this year : ");
        Expenses2012 = input.nextInt();
        int Sales2012;
        System.out.println("Please enter Sales for this year : ");
        Sales2012 = input.nextInt();

        int profit2012 = Sales2012 - Expenses2012;

    }
    if (selectedYear == 2) {
        int Expenses2013;
        System.out.println("Please enter Expenses for this year : ");
        Expenses2013 = input.nextInt();
        int Sales2013;
        System.out.println("Please enter Sales for this year : ");
        Sales2013 = input.nextInt();

        int profit2013 = Sales2013 - Expenses2013;

    }
    if (selectedYear == 3) {
        int Expenses2014;
        System.out.println("Please enter Expenses for this year : ");
        Expenses2014 = input.nextInt();
        int Sales2014;
        System.out.println("Please enter Sales for this year : ");
        Sales2014 = input.nextInt();

        int profit2014 = Sales2014 - Expenses2014;

    }try {
        main(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you see, I have the variables, and the graph is ready, I just do not know how to put them in a text file then read into an array to use them as the height of 3 rectangles (separating them in places of commas).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` and write your collections as an object to file. Later on you cen get your collection as the same object via `ObjectInputStream`